# upload file to php script on background

Tags: java, android

I want to upload a file (picture) to the server (PHP script), but in background. I am searching a very lightweight AsyncTask to do this, but I can't find any useful on Google.

Any Idea how I can upload a file to PHP with an AsyncTask? The upload Function should only get the local file as variable, every else should be not variable...

Maybe somebody can help me with that?

Answer (score -1):

**To perform task in background.**

You need to create the `service` and write the logic in that to upload the file to server.

Read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).